# How to run Rserve-Extension for Netlogo in local host using multiple cores simultaneously

Tags: r, tcp, netlogo, rserve, behaviorspace

I have a Mac 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion), 2.6GHz Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, Netlogo 5.0.4, Rserve-Extension 0.1beta, R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing".

I would like to run my NetLogo model, which sends variables to R via Rserve-Extension, using BehavSpace so that I can run it using at least 4 cores simultaneously.

My NetLogo model runs perfectly when I run it via the main interface (not using BehaviorSpace). However, when I try running it via BehaviorSpace using, say, 4 cores simultaneously, it appears to run in all 4 cores but only saves the results (the .csv files generated in R) from 1 model run. It also gives an initial error "with expected input to be an agent but got the number 0 instead" - it does not give this error when I run it via the main interface.

I have defined only 1 port:

```
rserve:init 6311 "localhost"
```

My doubt is, I guess, very simple... I have little experience with this...

Which code do I need to include in my NetLogo model with Rserve extension to be able to run it in multiple cores simultaneously using BehaviorSpace? Does it need 1 connection per core?

I tried the following code:

```
rserve:init 6311 "localhost"

rserve:init 6312 "localhost"
```

It connects the first localhost and gives an error message when it reaches the second line, saying that it is already connected (to the first).

Thank you
Eduardo

Comment: Maybe call the attention of the Rserve authors to this? (If they answer here, great, if they answer you privately, it would be great if you posted their answer here, in case anyone else has the same problem.)

Comment: also asked at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/How-to-run-Rserve-Extension-in-BehavSpace-using-multiple-connections-Mac-Mountain-Lion-td5004621.html

Answer (score 1):

Jan Thiele, the author of the Rserve-Extension for Netlogo, provided me with the answer for the question above in a a private email. For the benefit of others, I copy his answer below.

> "I currently see no solution to use the Rserve-Extension with multiple cores without modifying the variable names in R. The connection is not core specific but is available globally. In contrast, the R-Extension uses different environments and separates the variables from different cores from each other. Maybe a similar thing is possible with the Rserve-Extension - but I need to reflect carefully on how to achieve this -, which is difficult currently. An of course not nice workaround could be to split the BehaviorSpace experiment into several independent runs and start them in different NetLogo instances running each with a single process - of course, not nice!"

Eduardo